# Partially Highlighting input value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, focus

I Have a file listing page . In that page user can rename on clicking of the file name
.Currently on click of the file name it opens a input box , in that file name is highlighted with its extension. I want only file name to be focused , so that user will not rename the file extension. Can any one help me in jquery

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: trim the end file extension and after the user finished editing add it back

Comment: This isn't really a jQuery question: it's more about how to get HTML forms to do what you want. Basically, if you don't want something edited, don't put it in an INPUT box. However, this could be quite ugly. You'd probably be better checking the new value when the user submits the change and popping up a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var output = filename1.substr(0, filename1.lastIndexOf('.'))
```